# how to set hotsname in index name in fluentd conf file

Tags: fluentd

I want to set hostname in index_name of fluentd conf file. I am setting like this but it is not working

```
<match output.**>
   @type copy
   <store>
    @type elasticsearch
        host elasticsearch
      ssl_version TLSv1_2
      ssl_verify false
      type_name _doc
      port 443
      scheme https
      flush_interval 10s
      index_name abc-${hostname}
    </store>
    <store>
      @type stdout
    </store>
  </match>
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but let me try to answer anyway.
You can achive it in your source part.
Example

```
  <source>
   type tail
   #format json
   path path_to_the_file
   pos_file /var/log/td-agent/buffer/somename
   tag hostname #in plain text(there are other methods too)
  </source>
```

Now add

```
include_tag_key true
logstash_prefix ${tag}
logstash_format true
```

to your `<match>` part after host and remove `index_name..`
It's not a solution to your problem but it will give you a direction hopefully.